# Java share common functionality between enums using interfaces

Tags: java, enums, interface, abstract

I have a few enums that have the same functionality but contain different constants for organization reasons. They each look like this:

```
public enum OneEnum { 
    greenApple(apple, green),
    redApple(apple,red);

    private final String fruit;
    private final String type;

    private OneEnum (final String fruit, final String type) {
        this.fruit = fruit;
        this.type = type;
    }

    public String getFruit() {
        return fruit;
    }

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }
}
```

The other enums have the same private fields, constructor, and methods and only differ by listed constants. I was wondering how much of this code I can move to a common place such as interface (or abstract class if possible). I am able to create an interface such as:

```
public interface CommonEnum {
    String getFruit();
    String getType();
}
```

but can I do better than that?

Comment: Hint: what is the point of using an enum ... when you then use "raw strings" for other types such as Fruit or Type? Aren't those worth real types?

Comment: With enums being virtually final, this is not really possible. But why do the organization in separate enums? If they are that similar, perhaps you should put them in one enum, and just define EnumSets to group them?

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
public interface CommonEnum { ...

public class Holder implements CommonEnum() {
 private final String fruit ...

}

public enum OneEnum {
  GREEN_APPLE(new Holder(GREEN, APPLE)), ...

  private OneEnum(Holder holder) { this.holder = holder };

  public getHolder() { return holder };
```

In other words: if that "combination" of values is the "common thing" that you need in different places, than *that* should go into its own class.

Of course, the downside of this is: users of your enum would now be violating the Law of Demeter, as in:

```
Fruit fruit = OneEnum.GREEN_APPLE.getHolder().getFruit();
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't at all see the point in using an enum for the combination of values at all.

What you have in effect is

```
public enum Fruit {
    APPLE, ORANGE, BANANA //...
}

public enum Color {
    RED, GREEN, BLUE // ... 
}
```

and a combination of the two

```
class ColoredFruit {
    public final Fruit fruit;
    public final Color color;
    public ColoredFruit(Fruit f, Color c) { fruit = f; color = c; }
}
```

The enums you have are only instances

```
Collection<ColoredFruit> apples = Arrays.asList(new ColoredFruit(APPLE, RED), new ColoredFruit(APPLE, GREEN));
```

And if you do feel fancy, add interfaces

```
interface Fruit {
    FruitEnum getFruit();
}
interface Colored {
    Color getColor();
}
```

which `ColoredFruit` can implement by adding getters.